# Error when populating data in mongodb in MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I am working on a demo mean app which has a script which populates employee data into the mongo db. On running the populate script in node I am getting an error saying:

```
:/var/www/html/mean/hr$ node bin/populate_db.js
{ Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/mean/hr/node_modules/mongoose-post-find/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js:15:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/mean/hr/node_modules/mongoose-post-find/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/index.js:3:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
Deleting employees
Done deleting employees
Deleting teams
Done deleting teams
Adding employees
Done adding employees
Adding teams
Done adding teams
Updating employee teams
Done updating employee teams
Done!
```

My populate data scripts is as follows:

```
var async = require('async');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
require(process.cwd() + '/lib/connection');
var Employee = mongoose.model('Employee');
var Team = mongoose.model('Team');
var data = {
    employees: [{
            id: '1000003',
            name: {
                first: 'Colin',
                last: 'Ihrig'
            },
            image: 'images/employees/1000003.png',
            address: {
                lines: ['11 Wall Street'],
                city: 'New York',
                state: 'NY',
                zip: 10118
            }
        },
        {
            id: '1000021',
            name: {
                first: 'Adam',
                last: 'Bretz'
            },
            address: {
                lines: ['46 18th St', 'St. 210'],
                city: 'Pittsburgh',
                state: 'PA',
                zip: 15222
            }
        },
        {
            id: '1000022',
            name: {
                first: 'Matt',
                last: 'Liegey'
            },
            address: {
                lines: ['2 S Market Square', '(Market Square)'],
                city: 'Pittsburgh',
                state: 'PA',
                zip: 15222
            }
        },
        {
            id: '1000025',
            name: {
                first: 'Aleksey',
                last: 'Smolenchuk'
            },
            image: 'images/employees/1000025.png' /* invalid image */ ,
            address: {
                lines: ['3803 Forbes Ave'],
                city: 'Pittsburgh',
                state: 'PA',
                zip: 15213
            }
        },
        {
            id: '1000030',
            name: {
                first: 'Sarah',
                last: 'Gay'
            },
            address: {
                lines: ['8651 University Blvd'],
                city: 'Pittsburgh',
                state: 'PA',
                zip: 15108
            }
        },
        {
            id: '1000031',
            name: {
                first: 'Dave',
                last: 'Beshero'
            },
            address: {
                lines: ['1539 Washington Rd'],
                city: 'Mt Lebanon',
                state: 'PA',
                zip: 15228
            }
        }
    ],
    teams: [{
            name: 'Software and Services Group'
        },
        {
            name: 'Project Development'
        }
    ]
};
var deleteEmployees = function (callback) {
    console.info('Deleting employees');
    Employee.remove({}, function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error deleting employees: ' + error);
        }
        console.info('Done deleting employees');
        callback();
    });
};
var addEmployees = function (callback) {
    console.info('Adding employees');
    Employee.create(data.employees, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error: ' + error);
        }
        console.info('Done adding employees');
        callback();
    });
};
var deleteTeams = function (callback) {
    console.info('Deleting teams');
    Team.remove({}, function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error deleting teams: ' + error);
        }
        console.info('Done deleting teams');
        callback();
    });
};
var addTeams = function (callback) {
    console.info('Adding teams');
    Team.create(data.teams, function (error, team1) {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error: ' + error);
        } else {
            data.team_id = team1._id;
        }
        console.info('Done adding teams');
        callback();
    });
};
var updateEmployeeTeams = function (callback) {
    console.info('Updating employee teams');
    var team = data.teams[0];
    // Set everyone to be on the same team to start
    Employee.update({}, {
        team: data.team_id
    }, {
        multi: true
    }, function (error, numberAffected, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error updating employe team: ' + error);
        }
        console.info('Done updating employee teams');
        callback();
    });
};
async.series([
    deleteEmployees,
    deleteTeams,
    addEmployees,
    addTeams,
    updateEmployeeTeams
], function (error, results) {
    if (error) {
        console.error('Error: ' + error);
    }
    mongoose.connection.close();
    console.log('Done!');
});
```

I tried changing the bin folder to root of the app, but I still got the same error.

What is wrong?

Comment: Does the file `'/var/www/html/mean/hr/bin/lib/connection'` even exist?

Comment: yes it has the db details :
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dbUrl = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/hr'

Comment: Are you 100% sure that is the correct path? The error message is specifically complaining about not being able to find that file (error is on this line: `populate_db.js:3:1`). Could you try changing the require line to `require('./lib/connection');` ?

Comment: I tried doing that earlier. It gave and error stating the current path along with ./lib/connection as the module path. I am reffing to the book by Collin : https://g.co/kgs/MbQehX  , is it possible that the mongoose Version is deprecated. Or a connection error while connecting to the local mongodb. The book suggests to connect with : mongoose.connect(dbUrl);

Comment: on running the populate_db script from node , i.e through node /bin/populate_db.js i am getting error like this :
node bin/populate_db.js
{ Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)